# Is it possible to build a picklist dependant formula field that will display a dynamic date?

Tags: formula-field

I have a picklist, Type, and a date field, CloseDate. I want to create a formula field, Trigger, which equals CloseDate - 90 days when Type = Incremental, or equals N/A if Type is not Incremental.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you already try something ? Formulas aren't that hard, and much like excel formulas.

Comment: I had tried something very similar to what DavinC suggested but got the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
If(IsPickVal(StageName, 'Incremental'), CloseDate - 90, null)
```

Use a formula field which returns a date. Unfortunately you can't have text (N/A) in a date formula field so I've just put null if StageName != Incremental.

Comment: Did this work? I see above you mentioned a syntax problem.

Comment: Hi Davin, I'm afraid I can't remember. But I did get it working in the end.